# Existence of partial derivatives of a homogeneous function

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

Here is an exercise I found in R.Creighton Buck's advanced calculus:
A function f is said to be homoegeneous of degree $k$ in a neighborhood $N$ of the origin if $f(tx,ty)=t^k*f(x,y)$ for all points $(x,y)\in N$ and all $t\in[0,1]$. Assuming apprpriate continuity conditions, prove that $f$ satisfies in $N$ the differential equation $xf_1(x,y)+yf_2(x,y)=kf(x,y)$ where $f_1$ denotes the partial derivative with respect to the first coordinate.

Here is the question:
The differential equation can be easily derived once the existence of partial derivatives is proved. However I cannot prove it. I think of a special case where $N$ is a neighborhood containing the unit disc $D$, the function is first defined on the boundary of $D$ and then defined in the interior of $D$ by homogeneity. I think if $f$ doesn't behave well on the boundary, then existence  and continuity of the partial derivatives cannot be guaranteed. Can someone give me a counterexample or prove the existence.
PS: In Buck's book, the chain rule of composite functions $w=f(u,v)$ where $u=g(x,y)$ and $v=h(x,y)$ requires  $g,h,f$ to be of class $C'$.

Comment: Maybe you don't need to deal with the existence of the derivatives. If the exercise is cited correctly, you assume the continuity conditions whatever you need: "Assuming apprpriate continuity conditions".

Comment: What is the precise meaning of "appropriate continuity conditions"?

Comment: The textbook doesn't give a specific continuity condition. That's why I am confused about to what extent the condition is appropriate but not trivial.